# Propellerheads Figure - Export includes fade out making it difficult to loop

Tags: looping

I am trying to sequence some exports from the Propellerheads Figure app on IOS.

Unfortunately the exports all include a fade out (that is not present when using figure - it just loops perfectly).

I'm struggling to find the exact spot to crop in order to make the loop.

Does anyone have any suggestions?  If I could just make Figure not export with the fade out, that would be ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We embed tempo in the iTunes exports for those DAWs that use it (Reason), otherwise if you set the tempo of your loop you shouldn't have any troubles snipping that tail in your DAW of choice.

We include the tail for anyone who wants to paste it in the beginning of the loop, which would otherwise be dry.

AudioCopy just renders one pass of the loop, without tail.

AudioShare (http://kymatica.com/Software/AudioShare) is a great app for handling audio snippets on iOS!

Hope this helps!

/Kalle, Product Manager Apps, Propellerhead, twitter.com/kallepa

Comment: Thanks very much! I'll look for something that grabs it out the AudioCopy route.

Answer (score 0):

Extend the pattern that you're exporting so that the fade out occurs after the pattern that you're trying to crop?

Or record it directly.

Answer (score 0):

Would cutting the tail off with the fade at a point you think is appropriate then adding the tail with fade on a new track at the beginning of the loop help? Hard to know really without hearing it.